# Sendgrid cURL authentication GET API in php

Tags: php, rest, curl, sendgrid

So I've been trying to figure out how to manage this for a few days but nothing so far...

Here's my problem : I'm trying to retrieve a json object from a SendGrid GET API.
-> https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces/

Which needs cURL authentication, as the support told me :

```
curl --request GET \
 --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces/
  --header 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY' 
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

So since I'm pretty new to cURL, I can't manage to retrieve the datas with this :

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , 'authorization: Bearer MY_API_KEY'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$bounces = json_decode(file_get_contents($response),true);
```

I get this error :

```
Warning: file_get_contents({"errors":[{"field":null,"message":"resource not found"}]}): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...
```

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Have you tried: 
`$bounces = json_decode($response, true);` ?

Comment: I finally got through, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do what I wanted to do :

```
 //opening curl sessions
    $ch1 = curl_init('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces');
    $ch2 = curl_init('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/invalid_emails');

    //setting options to ch1
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , 'authorization: Bearer MY_API_KEY'));
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //setting options to ch2
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , 'authorization: Bearer MY_API_KEY'));
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //exec 2 curl sessions
    $resp1 = curl_exec($ch1);
    $resp2 = curl_exec($ch2);

//Merging 2 curl arrays and converting into json
    $array = json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($resp1, true),json_decode($resp2, true)));

//Decoding result
    $arr = json_decode($array, true);

    foreach ($arr as $data) {

        echo $data['email'].'<br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the curl

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Edited 
based on your JSON response I could try to parse with these

```
$response = '[{"created":1495048030,"email":"dfezfezfezfezfezfez@exelcia-it.com","reason":"550 5.4.1 [dfezfezfezfezfezfez@exelcia-it.com]: Recipient address rejected: Access denied [DB5EUR01FT015.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com] ","status":"5.4.1"},{"created":1494945503,"email":"squestgel@exelcia-it.com","reason":"550 5.4.1 [squestgel@exelcia-it.com]: Recipient address rejected: Access denied [DB5EUR01FT004.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com] ","status":"5.4.1"}]';
$json = json_decode($response , true) ; 
echo '<pre>'.print_r($json, true).'</pre>';
foreach ($json as $data) {
    echo $data['email'].'<br>';
}
```

And here is the result I got.

```
        Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [created] => 1495048030
            [email] => dfezfezfezfezfezfez@exelcia-it.com
            [reason] => 550 5.4.1 [dfezfezfezfezfezfez@exelcia-it.com]: Recipient address rejected: Access denied [DB5EUR01FT015.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com] 
            [status] => 5.4.1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [created] => 1494945503
            [email] => squestgel@exelcia-it.com
            [reason] => 550 5.4.1 [squestgel@exelcia-it.com]: Recipient address rejected: Access denied [DB5EUR01FT004.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com] 
            [status] => 5.4.1
        )

)

dfezfezfezfezfezfez@exelcia-it.com
squestgel@exelcia-it.com
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I actually figured it out, I had to put the url this way : https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces without the  '/' at the end. But now I get the raw json data in the page when I do curl_exec, but that's not what I want, I actually want to json decode the result and foreach it, but when I try $response = curl_exec($ch); and foreach($response as $key => $value)
{
  
      echo $value['email'].'<br>';
 
    }
I  get Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/gb/Desktop/MAMP/array 2.php on line 13

Comment: can you provide JSON response example.. did you decoded it as an object or an array ?

Comment: I answered you as a response above

Comment: please update your existing cURL code on your question

Comment: That's okay, I used your solution with curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); which allows me to get the datas, now I have to figure out how to get datas from 2 urls, I guess there are some curl functions to do that. Thanks man !

Comment: You can make if conditional.if succed continue next url else die or exit.. if my answer worked please marked as accepted so people now solution of this case.

Comment: It's okay now. Thanks for your help!